# Windows apache service won't connect to the SQLEXPRESS database. (ODBC, PHP)

Tags: php, sql, web, odbc

So I have this windows server 2012 VM that I installed a Knight Online game server on.

The game uses a SQL database. the same database needs to be connected to the web server to show info about the game server, login to your account, etc.

I installed Appserv v8.1.0 to run the apache service.
Anyway, everything works ONLY if I run httpd.exe manually, from the GUI. It works, but very slow, and it does not start the apache service (Windows services).

If I try to run the apache service as I should, the service runs, but when I try to get into the site I get this error:

> Warning: odbc_exec(): SQL error: [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server
>   Driver][SQL Server]The SELECT permission was denied on the object
>   '_WEBSETTINGS', database 'KN_Online', schema 'dbo'., SQL state 42000
>   in SQLExecDirect in C:\AppServ\www\library\dbo.lib.php(2) : eval()'d
>   code(1) : eval()'d code(1) : eval()'d code on line 27.

I want to remind you that if I run httpd.exe, the site runs, features work and I can connect to the accounts.

I would also add that the site's settings located in the DB itself. there are a few tables that belongs to the website.

I understand that it's authority issue. However I cant point on the exact problem, cause it works.

I hope that I've provided enough info about my case, if I missed anything please ask and I will reply right away :)

- The site is in PHP.
- Using SQLExpress & Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio.

Thanks in advance guys!

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so i solved this. the problem was that the user that ran the service had no permission to access the db. i changed the user the services logs on as to the right one and the problem got solved.

thanks anyway :)

peace.